# Inconsistent dbunit behaviour between platforms with null dates using in-memory h2

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2, dbunit

I'm running into an interesting issue here with a DBUnit test.

We have some code that we test with DBUnit tests and a xml dataset. I have inconsistent test results with exactly the same dataset and code files among platforms, so I decided to follow the trail as I will be refactoring a part of the DB Access classes.

The issue I'm running into is the following:

1. The Dataset has 3 records that match a certain query defined in a hbm file.
2. The query does an "order by DATE_FIELD desc", however not all the records in the dataset have this DATE_FIELD set (meaning it should be interpreted as null or the default value from the scripts, which are also identical on both platforms).

On one platform (Linux-server) where Maven runs the tests, they are all OK, however on my PC with Windows, the records are extracted from the database (dataset) with a different order, so I get an error when the test validates the order of the records.

So, I know that modifying the dataset will get my tests to go green on both sides, but if someone wrote this dataset without a date column in one of the records, he might have known about some business rule I'm not aware of, so I'm really not modifying the scenario as it might cause unforseen future problems.

After searching for an answer, I'm modifying the question. The answer I'm looking for, how do I get the H2 database to be consistent with null dates on different platforms. What parameter do I have to set to get NULLS FIRST or NULLS LAST for the whole DB without touching queries?

Thank you very much and regards.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Do you have *one* database server or do you have an instance of the database locally on both machines?

Comment: Hi, the application normally runs with DB2, but the DBUnit tests run with a dataset from a flat xml file. The dataset features are taken from this package: org.dbunit.dataset.

Comment: Maybe to be more clear, it's an h2 in-memory DBMS.

Comment: You actually didn't specify how the order is different. Please do so.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. Maybe you mean about the records. When run from maven, the records with the date field not set are at the end of the resultset, and on my pc the're on the beginning...

Comment: That sounds like different default values for the place NULLs should be put. The best way is to specify it explicitly by using `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAST`.

Comment: Well, I managed to get the test working by changing the order clause to order by case when DATE_FIELD is null then 0 else 1 end, DATE_FIELD desc, however I would rather like to know how to config this as a default behaviour without touching the queries. However I'm seeing it has nothing to do with dbunit, rather with H2 so I should close this question and look for the answer or post the more specific question.

Comment: Indeed, I think it is some default value of H2 that is either different or it reads it from some config file on the machine and that differs between the two.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm looking for. I have not found H2 documentation that helps me with this behaviour, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Well, I have found that sending a -Dh2.sortNullsHigh=true as a JVM parameter on the unit tests does the trick, but I don't like that approach as it is dependant on every eclipse configuration. I have a class where the whole H2 instance is configured, I'm now looking for clues on how I can set that property.

Comment: When you use the same version of H2 with the same data and parameters, then the sort order of `null` is the same on all platforms. I would check if you are using the same settings, the same database URL, the same system property and the same version of H2 on all platforms.

Comment: Well, in fact, in the central environment, maven runs the tests. I found the parameter in the pom file, however when you run the tests from eclipse, you don't initialize any maven environment, so that's the issue. However, I had to folow the trail to get the real cause of the problem, I really thought it was dbunit related, but it really was the DBMS (in this case. an in-memory H2 DB). Thank you and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

I'm answering my own question as I found an answer, a better follow-up would be nice but I think this gets to the point.

I followed the instructions on this page:

http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/SysProperties.html

And set the sortNullsHigh property on runtime, before loading the driver:

System.setProperty("h2.sortNullsHigh", "true");

Maybe later we will see a way to get it into a config file, after all the central unit tests run with jenkins/maven and there the property is set properly.

Regards